# Spark, check if some columns have True and then fill a new column with Y or N

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**I am trying to fill a new column with Y or N**.
To do that I check two columns and if one of this has a True value, I put Y in the new column else put a N.

*For example, I have this dataframe*:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+--------+-------------------+
|Date          |Col1      | Col2     |ChangeinCol1_Col2 | Col3   | Col4   | ChangeinCol3_Col4 |
+--------------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+--------+-------------------+
|2020-12-14    |True      | False    |     Y            | False  | False  |       N           |
|2020-12-14    |False     | False    |     Y            | False  | False  |       N           |
```

**If there is a True in Col1 or Col2, the column ChangeinCol1_Col2 will be Y**, same for ChangeinCol3_Col4 but in this case there are N because there are not changes in Col3 and Col4.

How could I do this with Apache Spark in Scala? I am trying it with df.withColumn to create the new column but don't know how to check the value in the cols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `when`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "ChangeinCol1_Col2",
    when(max($"Col1").over(Window.orderBy()) || max($"Col2").over(Window.orderBy()), lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N"))
).withColumn(
    "ChangeinCol3_Col4",
    when(max($"Col3").over(Window.orderBy()) || max($"Col4").over(Window.orderBy()), lit("Y")).otherwise(lit("N"))
)
```

Comment: But if what I have to check is if the col is True or False, if have a True, I put Y, else if the col only have Falses values, put N.

Comment: @MLstudent are the columns of boolean type? If yes, you can put them as a condition directly.

Comment: Btw thank you a lot for your help. In this way I only compare the value in the row, I have to check if for example, col1 or col2 have in any row a True, then all the new column, in this case, ChangeinCol1_Col2  will be Y, else N.

Comment: @MLstudent then you can use `max` instead. see edited answer.

Comment: Wow! is working! You have helped me a lot! and is not the first time, You helped me in the last question too! Could you explain me a little the performance of max and over here? And if you can, would you recommend me a course of Spark to learn this or something? Thanks a lot again!